# Adding to a parameter for category filtering

Tags: php

Ok so i have a question about PHP, and  I don't know if i'm just being stupid or if this is just a lot harder than i thought :/

So i'm trying to filter some results down through GET parameter's in the URL. I'm thinking the best way to do this would be similar to what ebuyer.com do.

When you filter there search results by different category's the URl is built up like so

```
filtercat=36,134,142,62 etc
```

How are they adding to the parameter whilst keeping the rest of the selected category's?

Help!

**I'm basically trying to create what is on [this site](http://www.ebuyer.com/search?page=1&sort=relevancy&limit=10&q=memory+card&filtercat=48,36), on the left sidebar where you can select and deselect filters for your search**

Many thanks for any replies

**UPDATE**

Below is some code but repeated clicking on the link causes multiple occurrences of the same value

e.g. categories.php?filtercat=361343636

how can I stop this and add commas in between so the output is?

e.g. categories.php?filtercat=36,134   etc

```
<?php 

$filter = $_GET['filtercat'];
$pieces = explode(",", $filter);
$edit_url = http_build_query( Array( 'filtercat' => ''.$pieces[0].$pieces[1].$pieces[2].'' ) ); 

echo($edit_url);
?>
```

Then in my links I have

```
<a href="<?php echo('categories.php?'.$edit_url.'36'); ?>">36catagory</a> 

<a href="<?php echo('categories.php?'.$edit_url.'134'); ?>">134catagory</a>
```

The explode does not work though as there are no commas... the whole things a giant mess really and I'm so confused :/ Help!

Comment: I think you mean "commas" (,,,), not "comers".

Comment: oops, Thanks for that Nathan :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to [`explode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php), you'll need [`implode()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php), and probably [`array_unique()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php).

```
$filter = $_GET['filtercat'];
$pieces = explode(',', $filter);

$edit_url = http_build_query( Array( 
    'filtercat' => implode(',', array_unique($pieces)) 
));
```

Answer (score 0):

script.php?filtercat[]=36&filtercat[]=134

Answer (score 0):

Another wat to pass multiple values like that is serializing an array with the values.

```
$array = array('filtercat' => 
    array(25, 32, 49)
);
$passme = serialize($array);
```

Then send $passme as GET.

```
<a href='test.php?val=<?php echo $passme; ?>'>Link</a>
```

Then you can unserialize it later and get the array containing all your values

```
$serilized = $_GET['val'];
$array = unserialize($serialized);
```

Which will print out as:

Array
(
    [filtercat] => Array
        (
            [0] => 25
            [1] => 32
            [2] => 49
        )
)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just use `http_build_query` to rebuild the querystring? I assume you know the value of all the `$_GET` parameters, so why bothering to append to the querystring, when you can rebuild it?